# Unable to use SQL Server Import/Export Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-import-wizard

I am currently working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and have just downloaded the SQL Server Import/Export Wizard. All I am trying to do is import data into my SQL environment from an Excel file. Something tells me that this should not be as hard of a process as it has been for me so far... I have been able to do this successfully in the past with txt files using the basic "Import Flat File" feature, but now I am running into problems when trying to use the Import/Export Wizard. When I click on "Tasks" and then "Import Data..." the Import/Export Wizard opens, but then when I click "Next" to move on to the next page where I can choose my file I am met with the following error:

[SQL Import/Export Wizard Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFudV.png)

I have absolutely no idea what any of this means and have not been able to find any helpful explanations elsewhere online. Any guidance as to how I might be able to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!